# Django REST Framework 3.0 - NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have this Error

```
IntegrityError at /foobars/
NOT NULL constraint failed: restServer_foobar.geo_location_id
```

When I try to add a new Foobar Object to DB over `http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobars/` (Website/APIView)

My Serializer Class looks like this:

```
class GeopointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Geopoint
        fields = ('id', 'latitude', 'longitude')

class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    geo_location = GeopointSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        fields = ('id', 'geo_location', 'geo_fence', 'registered', 'last_login')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        geo_location_data = validated_data.pop('geo_location')
        foobar = FooBar.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Geopoint.objects.create(FooBar=foobar, **geo_location_data)
        return foobar
```

DB was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ForeignKey` is on your `FooBar` model, not your `Geopoint` model. This determine the order that you need to create objects, because the fields in the database have to be filled correctly.

Objects which have foreign keys should always be created *after* the objects that they point to, because you can't fill it in afterwards - it has to exist when you create the object. In your case, that means you have to switch the location of your `create` statements, so the `Geopoint` is created before the `FooBar` object.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    geo_location_data = validated_data.pop('geo_location')
    geo_location = Geopoint.objects.create(**geo_location_data)
    foobar = FooBar.objects.create(geo_location=geo_location, **validated_data)
    return foobar
```

Note the changes in constructing each object.

Comment: Thanks solved my Problem. When I'm trying to PUT a foobar request over a simple iOS-App using AFNetworking I get a bad request 400 Error. Any idea, why it's working over Web/APIView and not from a "extern" request like an App?